# String assignment operator, applying a call to replace

Tags: javascript

Is there a javascript operator that updates a string in-place after a regex operation, such as:

```
ip = ip.replace(regex, 'xxx');
ip ?= ip.replace(regex, 'xxx');
```

Similar to the other arithmetic operators, such as:

```
x = x + 1;
x += 1;
```

Actually, now that I post it it's no shorter and doesn't make too much sense to have that.

Comment: `ip` in your example is a string, not a regex. But the short answer is no.

Comment: You ask about assigning to a regex, but present something else: assignment to a string. Which are you asking about?

Comment: @trincot I meant assigning to a string. -- a string after a regex operation has been applied to it.

Comment: just take the standard assignment. strings are immutable.

Comment: *"in-place"*: strings are immutable. There is no way to update a string "in-place".

Comment: Also, what have you researched?  All assignment operators are [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#assignment_operators)

Comment: @trincot aren't numbers immutable too though? `x += 1` is the same concept, right?

Comment: Yes, but that is not "in place" either.

Comment: @trincot oh got it. Maybe a better way to say it is just "with an assignment operator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such [shorthand assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#assignment_operators) exists.